# Grails war and include tests

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, build, war

I am looking for a way to run tests on war command of grails. War should not be created if test fails. I have searched a lot but did not find anything, Anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your **build.gradle**:

```
war.dependsOn test
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this on the command line

```
grails test-app && grails war
```

The second command won't execute if the first command fails